# Dialog de Alteração não tá exibindo os dados

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee, java-8

Eu tenho um projeto maven que tá usando o jsf, jpa e primefaces em que tem um dialog que tá sendo usado para fazer a altualização(update) dos dados, só que, o inputText fica vazio quando ele é chamados ao inves de aparecer os dados nele(que são os definidos no managedbean)... Como eu faço pra contornar isso?

Meu dialog

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" header="Effects" showEffect="explode"
        hideEffect="bounce" height="100" id="dialog">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Message" />
            <p:inputText value="#{growlView.message.message}"></p:inputText>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton
            action="#{growlView.save()}"
            value="Atualizar" onclick="PF('dialog').hide();" update=":listForm:grid, dialog" ></p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Minha listagem onde é chamado o dialog

Hello Word

```
<h:form id="listForm">
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <p:dataGrid value="#{growlView.allMessages}" var="bean" id="grid">
        <p:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputText value="Messagem:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{bean.message}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Alterar" onclick="PF('dialog').show();"
                action="#{growlView.preprarUpdate(bean)}"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Excluir"
                action="#{growlView.deleteMessage(bean)}" update="grid"></p:commandButton>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dataGrid>

</h:form>
<ui:include src="/faces/dialogEdit.xhtml" />
<p:commandButton value="Voltar" action="/faces/index.xhtml" process="@this"></p:commandButton>
```

Meu managedBean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.whit.domain.Message;
import com.whit.facade.MessageFacade;
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GrowlView extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    @Inject
    private Message message;

    private List<Message> messages;

    private MessageFacade messageFacade;

    public void save() {
        if (message.getId() == (null)) {
            createMessage();
        } else {
            updateMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private void createMessage() {
        try {
            getMessageFacade().createMessage(message);
            addSucess(message.getMessage());
            loadMessages();
            resetMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addFail(message.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            resetMessage();
        }
    }

    private void updateMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            getMessageFacade().updateMessage(message);
            addSucess(message.getMessage());
            loadMessages();
            resetMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addFail(message.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            getMessageFacade().deleteMessage(message);
            loadMessages();
            resetMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String preprarUpdate(Message message) {
        this.message = messageFacade.findMessage(message.getId());
        return ":dialog";
    }

    public MessageFacade getMessageFacade() {
        if (messageFacade == null) {
            messageFacade = new MessageFacade();
        }

        return messageFacade;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        if (messages == null) {
            loadMessages();
        }

        return messages;
    }

    private void loadMessages() {
        messages = getMessageFacade().listAll();
    }

    public void resetMessage() {
        message = new Message();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá pessoal. Depois de fazer as alterações que o douglas sugeriu e não ter sucesso eu pesquisei e decidir tentar substituir o onclick pelo oncomplete ai funcionou... Obrigado pela atenção. Espero que está solução seja util pra mais pessoas

Comment: Não é necessário adicionar RESOLVIDO no título. Apenas marcar uma resposta como aceite já sinaliza q foi solucionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendo você retornar o próprio objeto ao invés de `String`, mas olha.
No seu método:

```
public String preprarUpdate(Message message) {
        this.message = messageFacade.findMessage(message.getId());
        return ":dialog";
    }
```

você deve retornar o objeto para edição, então ficaria assim:

```
public String preprarUpdate(Message message) {
        this.message = messageFacade.findMessage(message.getId());
        return message;
    }
```

E após acionar seu botão você precisa atualizar o dialog, ficando assim:

```
<p:commandButton value="Alterar" onclick="PF('dialog').show();"
                action="#{growlView.preprarUpdate(bean)}" update=":<idform>:dialog"/>
```

Uma dica pra você sobre o jsf, você não precisa fechar seu componente como você fez com `</p:commandButton>`, só faz assim quando tem outro componente dentro, no seu caso como não tem pode fazer como no meu exemplo.

Comment: Eu fiz conforme você disse ai agora o dialog tá aparecendo com o conteudo no input e logo depois some. Ai eu tentei tirar o update, e o dialog aparece normalmente só que sem o conteudo. Alguma outra sugestão

Comment: Coloca um `process=@this` no button Alterar

Comment: nem precisou. eu fiz as alterações que você sugeriu e subtituir o onclick pelo oncomplete e deu certo.